# AfterUpdate - combine multiple actions

Tags: vba, ms-access

I hope you can help, I am new to VBA, but eager to learn.  I have created a form which adds a Document Number to my database (field name DocNum). I created an "afterupdate" event for that field to create a corresponding record on each table which will hold additional information for that document ID.  See code here:

```
Private Sub DocNum_AfterUpdate()
Dim TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer As DAO.Recordset

Set TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM    [TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer]")
TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer.AddNew
TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer![Manuscript_Number] = Me.DocNum.Value
TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer.Update
TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer.Close
Set TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub DocNum_AfterUpdate()

Dim TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer As DAO.Recordset

Set TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM [TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer]")
TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer.AddNew
TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer![Manuscript_Number] = Me.DocNum.Value
TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer.Update
TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer.Close
Set TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub DocNum_AfterUpdate()

Dim TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview As DAO.Recordset

Set TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM [TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview]")
TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview.AddNew
TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview![Manuscript_Number] = Me.DocNum.Value
TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview.Update
TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview.Close
Set TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub DocNum_AfterUpdate()

Dim TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications As DAO.Recordset

Set TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM [TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications]")
TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications.AddNew
TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications![Manuscript_Number] = Me.DocNum.Value
TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications.Update
TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications.Close
Set TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications = Nothing

End Sub
```

However, I get the following error when I try to use the form:

"The expression After Update you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Ambiguous name detected: DocNum_AfterUpdate."

After doing some research, I tried rewriting the code as one Private Sub, instead of four, as shown here:

```
Private Sub DocNum_AfterUpdate()
Dim TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer As DAO.Recordset

Set TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM [TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer]")
TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer.AddNew
TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer![Manuscript_Number] = Me.DocNum.Value
TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer.Update
TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer.Close
Set TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer = Nothing

Dim TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer As DAO.Recordset

Set TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM [TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer]")
TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer.AddNew
TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer![Manuscript_Number] = Me.DocNum.Value
TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer.Update
TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer.Close
Set TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer = Nothing

Dim TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview As DAO.Recordset

Set TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM [TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview]")
TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview.AddNew
TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview![Manuscript_Number] = Me.DocNum.Value
TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview.Update
TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview.Close
Set TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview = Nothing

Dim TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications As DAO.Recordset

Set TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM [TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications]")
TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications.AddNew
TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications![Manuscript_Number] = Me.DocNum.Value
TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications.Update
TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications.Close
Set TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications = Nothing

End Sub
```

However, this is not working either. It only updates TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications, and not tables 3, 4, or 5.

I've been searching for about 2 hours on how to have multiple afterupdate events, but nothing seems to be helping. The If>Then doesn't seem to apply, the For>Next doesn't either.

I'd love some help, thanks!
-Deb

Comment: I believe your `AfterUpdate` sub should be in the table object for the source table that detects the change in Document Number. If the event catcher (`AfterUpdate`) is in the userform object or in an independent sub (in a module) there's no direct connection to the actual table you're trying to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run action append queries without any recordsets. And since you are passing values from user input forms, consider paramterization with [QueryDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx). And to keep it a DRY-er solution (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself), a function can be used for each query call.

```
Private Sub DocNum_AfterUpdate()
   Dim strSQL

   ' TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer APPEND
   strSQL = "PARAMETERS DocNumParam TEXT(255);" _
            & " INSERT INTO [TBL_3_ManuscriptPrimaryReviewer] ([Manuscript_Number]) " _
            & " VALUES (DocNumParam)"

   Call RunQuery(strSQL)

   ' TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer APPEND
   strSQL = "PARAMETERS DocNumParam TEXT(255);" _
            & "INSERT INTO [TBL_4_ManuscriptSTATReviewer] ([Manuscript_Number]) " _
            & " VALUES (DocNumParam)"

   Call RunQuery(strSQL)

   ' TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview APPEND
   strSQL = "PARAMETERS DocNumParam TEXT(255);" _
            & "INSERT INTO [TBL_5_ManuscriptSCReview] ([Manuscript_Number]) " _
            & " VALUES (DocNumParam)"

   Call RunQuery(strSQL)

   ' TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications APPEND
   strSQL = "PARAMETERS DocNumParam TEXT(255);" _
            & "INSERT INTO [TBL_6_ManuscriptPublications] ([Manuscript_Number]) " _ 
            & " VALUES (DocNumParam)"

   Call RunQuery(strSQL)

End Sub

Public Function RunQuery(stmt As String)
    Dim qdef As QueryDef

    Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", stmt)

    ' BIND PARAM VALUE
    qdef!DocNumParam = Me.DocNumValue

    ' EXECUTE ACTION
    qdef.Execute, dbFailOnError

    Set qdef = Nothing
End Function
```

---

However, your database design can be optimized with normalization. Instead of multiple similarly structured tables requiring updates and maintenance, use **one** table (i.e., `TBL_REVIEWERS`) with indicator such as *Type*. Further, querying data will be much easier.

```
ID   Type                       Manuscript_Number      ...
1    PrimaryReviewer            12345
2    ManuscriptSTATReviewer     12345
3    ManuscriptSCReview         12345
4    ManuscriptPublications     12345
```

Then your append query would modify for two values for same query call (even DRY-er).

```
Private Sub DocNum_AfterUpdate()
    Dim var As Variant 
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "PARAMETERS TypeParam TEXT(255), DocNumParam TEXT(255);" _
                & " INSERT INTO [TBL_Reviewers] ([Type], [Manuscript_Number]) " _
                & " VALUES (TypeParam, DocNumParam)"

    ' RUN APPEND QUERIES
    For Each var In Array("PrimaryReviewer", "ManuscriptSTATReviewer" _
                          "ManuscriptSCReview", "ManuscriptPublications")
        Call RunQuery(strSQL, var)
    Next var
End Sub

Public Function RunQuery(strSQL As String, strType As String)
    Dim qdef As QueryDef

    Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

    ' BIND PARAM VALUES
    qdef!TypeParam = strType
    qdef!DocNumParam = Me.DocNumValue

    ' EXECUTE ACTION
    qdef.Execute, dbFailOnError

    Set qdef = Nothing
End Function
```